# How to capture the Model.DoesNotExist exception in Django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

In Django REST Framework, when you query a database model and it does not exist an exception will be raised as `ModelName.DoesNotExist`.

This exception will change according to the model name.

For example:

- Querying the `Car` model will raise `Car.DoesNotExist`
- Querying the `Plane` model will raise `Plane.DoesNotExist`

This causes trouble, since you can not catch the exception at one common place, because you do not know the parent class of the Exception.

You have to catch a different exception every time you query a different model, for example:

```py
try:
    return Car.objects.get(pk=1)
except Car.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404
```

Why was this feature designed like this?

Is it possible to capture a common exception?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`ObjectDoesNotExist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

try:
    return Car.objects.get(pk=1)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    raise Http404
```

`ObjectDoesNotExist` will catch `DoesNotExist` exceptions for all models.

Django also provides [`get_object_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) shortcut so you dont need to raise Http404 explicitly.

Comment: Thanks but why django provided a detailed Exception when it already have the ObjectDoesNotExist

Comment: @KramerLi Django provides a DoesNotExist exception as an attribute of each model class to identify the class of object that could not be found and to allow you to catch a particular model class with try/except.

Comment: @KramerLi from this part of the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#doesnotexist